# PythonScraping a Website that Requires Login

Tags: python, python-3.x

Right, so I understand how to scrape a website, but I'm having trouble using Python 3 to login to a site I'm trying to scrape.

I've included the HTML  that the site uses. As I understand this is what is needed?

I tried a simple solution that appeared should work but hasn't (it appears to not login, and goes straight to the destination URL, skipping the login?).

```
Attempted Solution: https://pastebin.com/AEK6Qwnb (I've also tried a solution using RoboBrowser, but I couldn't succeed there either.) 
Website HTML: https://pastebin.com/Jp8Zpq2a
```

Let me know if this information isn't sufficient and I can try to provide more.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of possible solutions to this that will depend on the site, your needs and limitations as well as personal preference. However, a straight-forward solution is possible with [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

```
from selenium import webdriver

account = 'account'
password = 'password'

browser = webdriver.get('desktop/test.html')
browser.find_element_by_id('Account').send_keys(account)
browser.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password)
```